# ROS2 Python relative import of my scritps

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I have a project on Raspberry pi 3, a compiled ROS2 foxy from source, install Kivy and everything if fine. But now I'm trying to port my UI from ROS1 to ROS2 and I can't figure out how to do relative imports like from utils. See to code.

Package(ROS2) hierarchy:

```
control_panel_ui
├── control_panel_ui
│   ├── graphical_interface.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── listeners
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── start_listeners.py
│   ├── media
│   │   └── image.png
│   └── utils
│       ├── dict_services.py
│       ├── get_rpc.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── states.py
│       └── vehicle_state.py
├── package.xml
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── ...
```

And the code. Kivy is imported fine but my code such as utils, listeners etc. doesn't.

```
#kivy.require('1.7.2')
from kivy.app import App
 ...
from kivy.clock import Clock

from .utils.vehicle_state import VehicleState
from .utils.dict_services import dict_serv
from .utils.get_rpc import get_rpc_function

...
```

After the colcon build [package].py is moved to the install directory but those utils doesn't and then it it says cannot find package.

**edited:**
Maybe the thing is I don't know how to configure setup.py/.cfg. Maybe a link or an example would be great. I was not able to find anything uselful.

added setup.py/.cfg

```
from setuptools import setup

package_name = 'control_panel_ui'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],    
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml'])
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='pi',
    maintainer_email='michal@michal.com',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'control_panel_ui = control_panel_ui.graphical_interface:graphical_interface'
        ],
    },
)
```

cfg

```
[develop]
script-dir=$base/lib/control_panel_ui
[install]
install-scripts=$base/lib/control_panel_ui
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349790/ros2-python-relative-import-of-my-scritps/) by [robopo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26642/robopo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2020-04-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-04-20**:
You need to share the content of your `setup.py` / `setup.cfg` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The subdirectories are not available because in the `setup.py` file you only specify the first level directory:

```
packages=[package_name]
```

Instead of enumerating them explicitly I suggest you use the function provided by `setuptools` to find them:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
packages=find_packages(exclude=['test'])
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LSD](https://answers.ros.org/users/62065/lsd/) on 2021-05-27**:
Thank you so much! This answer is truly a lifesaver!